# Kotlin singleton in a subclass

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, singleton

I'm writing a framework in which I have difficulties to write a generic singleton class which need to be specialized by the user.

I would like the use being able to write something like:

```
class CustomClass protected constructor() : BasicClass()
```

with the framework being able to write:

```
BasicClass.instance
```

returning a BasicClass singleton

And the user being able to write:

```
CustomClass.instance
```

returning the same instance, but as a CustomClass singleton instance.

I have two possibilities in mind

**Case #1: Singleton is managed by user of the class**

```
class CustomClass private constructor() : BasicClass() {
    private object Holder {
        val INSTANCE = CustomClass()
    }

    companion object {
        val instance: CustomClass by lazy {
            Holder.INSTANCE
        }
    }
}
```

But I have no instance reference in the BasicClass side, and user need to implement singleton each time.

**Case #2: Singleton is managed by the framework**
Which I'm not able to write properly

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: a singleton is something that gets created once. so if you create a singleton for your base class such as Automobile, and then you create classes Truck and Racecar which extend this. In your example, you want the singleton reference from Automobile to be a Truck or a Racecar. However, an automobile is not a truck or a racecar, but a racecar and a truck are automobiles. If the above would work, the static reference could be a Truck and Racecar at the same time and that isn't possible.

Comment: I got it, for sure I won't allow two different  instance, but only one. In your terminology, I would like to have only one Automobile in my framework, but I need the framework user to be able to derive my class to implement some specific logic.

Comment: Would the object type help your cause? https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/kotlin-singletons-with-argument-194ef06edd9e

Comment: Maybe, but I did not figure out how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking a bit out of the box here, specially since there's not much context on what you actually need those classes to look like. Basically, if you want the framework to handle the singleton, you'll need to do one of two:

1. Auto-discover implementations of the `BasicClass` (either at runtime, or with an annotation and do code generation)
2. Provide users with a way to explicitly set what the implementing class would be

This could be an implementation for 2:

```
// This is the class that users of the framework want to extend
abstract class BasicClass

// This is the way both the framework and users can access the singleton instance
object Singleton {

    // The way users can set how an instance of the desired class is constructed
    var provider: (() -> BasicClass)? = null
        set(value) {
            if (field == null) {
                field = value
            } else {
                throw IllegalStateException("You can only register one provider for Singleton")
            }
        }

    val value: BasicClass by lazy {
        provider
                ?.invoke()
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("You need to declare your instance provider")
    }

    inline fun <reified T : BasicClass> get(): T {
        return value as? T
                ?: throw NullPointerException("Instance is of wrong type ${value.javaClass.name}")
    }
}
```

Now, users of your framework can do stuff like:

```
class CustomClass private constructor() : BasicClass() {
    companion object {
        val instanceProvider: () -> BasicClass = { CustomClass() }
    }
}
```

And, depending on the lifecycle of their code, they can register the class as

```
ClassInstance.provider = CustomClass.instanceProvider
```

Finally, in your framework you can do:

```
val basic: BasicClass = ClassInstance.get()
```

And users can do both:

```
val basic: BasicClass = ClassInstance.get()
val custom: CustomClass = ClassInstance.get()
```

Comment: Thank you @marianosimone for your help. This is an appropriate answer to my question. I don't find any button to close it.  I didn't want to describe too much the context, in order not to be too chatty... What I didn't know in your answer is the reifed function able to cast to the two classes. This match perfectly to my needs. Thank you ! (@moderator, can you close the question)?

Comment: Glad it helped, @AnthonyCFE. You can probably adapt it you match your needs better. As per accepting the answer, this should give you the right steps: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers